# Tomcat: HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I'm following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/implementing-jsp-on-netbeans-ide) example, I created a `index.jsp` file in the project `WebApplication1` with the following code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>First JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>Today's date</h1>
   Date and Time: <%= (new java.util.Date().toString())%>
</body>

</html>
```

The file is located in `WEB-INF` folder. Following the tutorial instructions, I built the project (success), then I ran it (also no exceptions). But when I go to `localhost:8080/WebApplication1`' it shows `404` mistake. I also tried the `localhost:8080/WebApplication1/index` with the same result..

EDIT1: I also tried to copy the `WebApplication1` folder from where Netbeans places it and pasting it into `tomcat/webapps` and running the simpliest `index.html` with the same (`404`) result..

EDIT2: Figured out the solution - the `localhost:8080/WebApplication1/web/index.jsp` works fine!

Comment: @BalusC, Thank you, I'll look into oracle tutorials. But the suggested answer (placing index.jsp outside the WEB-INF folder) didn't work for me..

Answer (score 1):

Move your `index.jsp` outside the `WEB-INF` folder. According to the Tutorial, the `index.jsp` is not **IN** the `WEB-INF` folder but actually it is **IN** the `web` folder.

`web/WEB-INF/index.jsp` should be `web/index.jsp`